# Get item from JSON file base on key failed although it exist in file

Tags: python, json

I have this JSON file with several keys inside:

```
{
  "button-SAVE": {
    "1.0.2.1.": {
      "by": "id",
      "locator": "com.shs.locator:id/tvSave"
    },
    "1.0.0": {
      "by": "xpath",
      "locator": "//div/span/a"
    },
    "1.0.1": {
      "by": "xpath1",
      "locator": "//div/span"
    }
  },
  "text-SAVE": {
    "1.0.2.1.": {
      "by": "id",
      "locator": "com.shs.locator:id/tvSave"
    },
    "1.0.0": {
      "by": "xpath",
      "locator": "//div/span/a"
    },
    "1.0.1": {
      "by": "xpath1",
      "locator": "//div/span"
    }
  },
  "text-HOST": {
    "1.0.2.1.": {
      "by": "id",
      "locator": "com.shs.locator:id/etHost"
    },
    "1.0.2": {
      "by": "id",
      "locator": "/ADD"
    }
  },
  "button-close": {
    "1.0.1": {
      "by": "css",
      "locator": "div span"
    },
    "1.0.2": {
      "by": "css",
      "locator": "div span a"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to return the element with key `button-SAVE` and version `1.0.2.1`.
This is what I have tried:

Load my JSON file:

```
with open('file.json') as f:
    json = load(f)
```

**Search**

```
item = json['button-SAVE'].get('1.0.2.1', None)
```

And this returns `None` although the element exist based on the given `key`.

Comment: dont use `json` as the name of the variable.  What is the `load` call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a dot after `'1.0.2.1'`. Given the json you provided, do this:

```
item = json['button-SAVE'].get('1.0.2.1.', None)
```